# Error with CMake and linking libraries

Tags: c++, cmake

I have a project using `ITK` and `VTK` libraries and a `CMakeLists` file which I can use to generate my project. I am now trying to use a new let of libraries (`VMTK`). It comes with a `CMake` use file which I include in `CMakeLists` to import the source and libraries. The problem I am having is that it is not properly generating the correct paths to the libraries. I get the following error when I try to compile my project:

```
Creating library C:/itkProjects/repository/ITK_source/vmtk/vmtkcenterline/source/build/Debug/vmtkcenterline.lib and object C:/itkProjects/repository/ITK_source/vmtk/vmtkcenterline/source/build/Debug/vmtkcenterline.exp
2>vmtkcenterline.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: static class vtkvmtkCapPolyData * __cdecl vtkvmtkCapPolyData::New(void)" (__imp_?New@vtkvmtkCapPolyData@@SAPAV1@XZ) referenced in function "public: static class vtkSmartPointer<class vtkvmtkCapPolyData> __cdecl vtkSmartPointer<class vtkvmtkCapPolyData>::New(void)" (?New@?$vtkSmartPointer@VvtkvmtkCapPolyData@@@@SA?AV1@XZ)
2>C:\itkProjects\repository\ITK_source\vmtk\vmtkcenterline\source\build\Debug\vmtkcenterline.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

The libraries should be included by the `CMake` use file. This *usefile* is pasted below:

```
INCLUDE(CMakeImportBuildSettings)

SET (VMTK_CPP_SOURCE_DIRS "C:/vmtk/source/vtkVmtk")

SET(VMTK_INCLUDE_DIRS
  ${VMTK_CPP_SOURCE_DIRS}
  ${VMTK_CPP_SOURCE_DIRS}/Common
  ${VMTK_CPP_SOURCE_DIRS}/ComputationalGeometry
  ${VMTK_CPP_SOURCE_DIRS}/Contrib
  ${VMTK_CPP_SOURCE_DIRS}/DifferentialGeometry
  ${VMTK_CPP_SOURCE_DIRS}/IO
  ${VMTK_CPP_SOURCE_DIRS}/Misc
  ${VMTK_CPP_SOURCE_DIRS}/Segmentation
  "C:/vmtk/build/VMTK-Build"
  "C:/vmtk/build/VMTK-Build/vtkVmtk"
  "C:/vmtk/build/Install/include/vmtk"
  "C:/vmtk/build/VMTK-Build/bin/Debug"
)

INCLUDE(
  "C:/vmtk/build/VMTK-Build/VMTKLibraryDepends.cmake"
)

SET(VMTK_LIBRARY_DIRS "C:/vmtk/build/VMTK-Build/bin")

SET(VMTK_USE_FILE
  "C:/vmtk/build/VMTK-Build/VMTKUse.cmake"
)

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${VMTK_INCLUDE_DIRS})

LINK_DIRECTORIES(${VMTK_LIBRARY_DIRS})

LINK_LIBRARIES(vtkvmtkCommon vtkvmtkComputationalGeometry vtkvmtkContrib vtkvmtkDifferentialGeometry vtkvmtkIO vtkvmtkITK vtkvmtkMisc vtkvmtkSegmentation nl tet)
```

How can I properly include the libraries? The direct path to the libraries is:

```
C:\vmtk\build\VMTK-Build\bin\Debug
```

can I directly set the path to them?

**PS:** In case it helps the `CMakeLists` is [here.](http://pastebin.com/DCyiuAFM)

Comment: If it helps, I had a similar problem with `CMake` and the link stage when building the `PCL 1.7 TRUNK` library. I had to manually edit the `link.txt` files in the `build` directory for each module and add there thee missing dependencies. For example, for `quazip`, the file would be in `build_dir/quazip/CMakeFiles/quazip.dir`. In that directory there are also some files for the includes.

Comment: ive added
`find_package(VMTK REQUIRED)`

`INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${vmtkcenterline_SOURCE_DIR}/include ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR} ${ITK_DIR} ${VTK_DIR} ${VMTK_INCLUDE_DIRS})`

`target_link_libraries(vmtkcenterline ${ITK_LIBRARIES} ${VTK_LIBRARIES} ${VMTK_LIBRARIES} ITKCommon vtkvmtkCommon vtkvmtkComputationalGeometry vtkvmtkContrib vtkvmtkDifferentialGeometry vtkvmtkIO vtkvmtkITK vtkvmtkMisc vtkvmtkSegmentation nl tet)`

now i get the error `LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'vtkvmtkComputationalGeometry.lib` when I try to compile, I guess this is an improvement?

Comment: At least it seems that you have advanced a bit... So, does `vtkvmtkComputationalGeometry.lib` exist? And if it exists, is the path to the library the right one?

Comment: i made a mistake when pasting the error message (i had removed vtkvmtkCommon from my cmake lists to try see if it worked.) the error i am getting is `LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'vtkvmtkCommon.lib'`
These files exist, they are located in C:\vmtk\build\VMTK-Build\bin\Debug how do I check if cmake has the correct path to these libraries, i am assuming that it does not

Comment: Well. Now this is the same problem I had with `PCL`. In this spot, I had to manually hack the `link.txt` file for the module where the linking error appeared and add the `-L<path_to_lib> -l<lib>`. They were missing in that file and I still don't know why `CMake` ignored some of the dependencies, even though they were listed in the GUI and it recognized them.

Comment: By the way, I used `MinGW`, but I don't think that should matter.

Comment: hm, im looking for link.txt but i dont find it anywhere. do you mean by vtkvmtkCommon ?

Comment: Mmmm, try using `grep` in the build directory to find the `link.txt` files. I'm not an expert with `CMake` so I can't help you further. For me, manually editing the `link.txt` files worked fine. :(

Comment: I don't know if this is still an issue or not with you, but I just ran into the same problem...  with CMake not linking in libraries (from ITK in my case).  To solve, I added:

    link_directories ( /usr/local/lib )
    target_link_libraries( myApp ITKSys-4.7 ITKCommon-4.7)

That seemed to do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is still an issue or not with you, but I just ran into the same problem... with CMake not linking in libraries (from ITK in my case). To solve, I added:

```
link_directories(/usr/local/lib)
target_link_libraries(myApp ITKSys-4.7 ITKCommon-4.7)
```

That seemed to do the trick.